# What is the standard format for localised resource files on different development platforms?

Tags: localization, resources, file-format

When developing in .Net, the framwork provides resx files as the standard way of storing localised resources (e.g. tranlsations of UI text).

I would like to know if there is a standard format for this in other development platforms (e.g. Java, RoR, etc.) and what that format is.

Thank you!

**Please limit each answer to one development technology (e.g Java/C++/PHP etc.)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Java, Adobe Flex also uses [ResourceBundles](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/resources/ResourceBundle.html) that are serialized to [.properties](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_6.html) files

Answer (score 2):

Java uses [Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), which are key-value pairs.

They can be serialized to the following two formats:

1. .properties

   `foo=bar`
2. .XML

   `<entry key="foo">bar</entry>`

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/posix-nls.html

There is a standard, called POSIX, that applies to just about every other non-Windows operating system.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php for the PHP-specific implementation of internationalization.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked into this in detail, but at first glance this seems a bit C specific to me.  I'm not convince for instance that a PHP developer would use this.

Comment: @Sosh: Why do you mention PHP?  Is that part of your question?  If it's part of your question, please update your question to include additional facts.

Comment: Well, I'm interested in what a developer would use in *each individual development environment*.  Your comment seems to imply that anything non windows would use this, which I dissagree with - hence the PHP example.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/Programmers.html which describes the relationship between posix-nls (the catgets() function) and the GNU gettext library which is more common for managing localization on Unix platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Large translation vendors accept the [TMX file](http://www.lisa.org/Translation-Memory-e.34.0.html) format for interchange of translation strings. Because they only have to deal with a standard xml file rather than strings embedded in controls, the amount of work these vendors have to do is reduced and so are their fees.

Comment: TMX is used for translation memories. Document translations are better stored in XLIFF files.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this on Linux is to use the [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) library, which stores its translations in .po files.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa applications (Mac/iPhone) are distributed as bundles (essentially: folders but with a known file-ish type). Inside a bundle, you can provide copies of strings files or other localized resources in a locale-specific subfolder. The Xcode provides IDE support for this, and the Cocoa frameworks provide many methods to conveniently fetch these resources.

See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternatAndLocaliz.html for details.